# Add element to existing Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have [this canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/y4trpr15/2/), where I am using [ChartJs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart) and would like to make the **legend** merge in to **graphic canvas**.

See my code:

```js
var radarChartData = {
  labels: ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"],
    
    datasets: [
   {
    label: "Linha1",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [2,2,2,2]
   },
   {
    label: "Linha2",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [8,8,8,8]
   }
  ]
 };

 window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
            responsive: true,
        //scaleShowLabels : true,
        animationSteps: 80,
        animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        angleShowLineOut : false,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
        
        legendTemplate : '<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                    +'<h3 style=\"color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\">.'
                    +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% }%>'
                +'<% } %></h3>',
        
        //Number - Pixel width of the angle line
    angleLineWidth : 100,

    //String - Point label font declaration
    pointLabelFontFamily : "Arial",

    //String - Point label font weight
    pointLabelFontStyle : "normal",

    //Number - Point label font size in pixels
    pointLabelFontSize : 20,

    //String - Point label font colour
    pointLabelFontColor : "black",
         // String - Template string for single tooltips
            tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value %>",
            // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
            multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> : <%= value %>",
        });

document.getElementById("legendDiv").innerHTML = window.myRadar.generateLegend();
```

```css
#canvas-container {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    canvas {
        display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
<div id="legendDiv"></div>
```

I am currently entering the legend in a `div`. Is there any way to insert it into the `canvas`?

I wish both the graph as the legend were part of a single `canvas`.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/y4trpr15/7/).

I generated a new canvas with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Code:

```js
$("#newCanvas").click(function () {
    var $conteudo = $("#canvas-container");
    html2canvas($conteudo[0], {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $('#canvas-container').after(canvas);
            var base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            console.log(base64);
        },
        logging: true
    });
});

var radarChartData = {
  labels: ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"],
    
    datasets: [
   {
    label: "Linha1",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [2,2,2,2]
   },
   {
    label: "Linha2",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [8,8,8,8]
   }
  ]
 };

 window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
            responsive: true,
        //scaleShowLabels : true,
        animationSteps: 80,
        animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        angleShowLineOut : false,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
        
        legendTemplate : '<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                    +'<h3 style=\"color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\">.'
                    +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% }%>'
                +'<% } %></h3>',
        
        //Number - Pixel width of the angle line
    angleLineWidth : 100,

    //String - Point label font declaration
    pointLabelFontFamily : "Arial",

    //String - Point label font weight
    pointLabelFontStyle : "normal",

    //Number - Point label font size in pixels
    pointLabelFontSize : 20,

    //String - Point label font colour
    pointLabelFontColor : "black",
         // String - Template string for single tooltips
            tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value %>",
            // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
            multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> : <%= value %>",
        });

document.getElementById("legendDiv").innerHTML = window.myRadar.generateLegend();
```

```css
#canvas-container {
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid #8AC007;
        background-color: white;
    }

    canvas {
        display: inline;
        background-color: white;
    }

    #legendDiv {
        text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="legendDiv"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<input id="newCanvas" type="button" value="New Canvas Now!"></input>
```